# Widget container to display SharePoint 2010 web parts

Tags: 2010

I have a requirement to build a widget container which is having behavior of expandable, collapsible, configurable widget title and content displayed in the widget with the **configurable source as SharePoint WebParts (OOB and third party web parts)**.

Need to predefine the page layout to have widgets with 3 (rows) * 2 (columns)  matrix, where user can configure each widget with the source as the SharePoint web part (document list, image rollover, third party forums web part etc.) and personalize their dashboard.

I don't know the possibility of implementing this requirement in SharePoint 2010 as i am new to it.

could anyone please help me in making me understand the implementation perspective of how we can build generic widget component with the source as a SharePoint web part.

Answer (score 1):

You looking to write a wrapper which can contain a Web Part in itself, but that should again be a Web Part so that it can act like a Widget and can be dropped into Web Part Zones, SharePoint already offers Drag and Drop and treat them as Widgets... The only thing it doesn't offer is collapsible, expandable...

> Do we need to build custom web part wrapper by extending the base web part? we don't want to define a custom page layout having web part zones to give users the ability to place web parts in them.

You may look into extending the existing Web Part class to add this functionality... Induce some JavaScript into the existing Web Part to add expandable/collapsible nature! All theory, never tried this :)

> we want to build a page with simple boxes (say DIV with button) in the fixed positions on the page. when user click on the button want to show all the OOB parts in SharePoint installed along with third party web parts using object model. once user selects the web part, the selected web part output should be shown in that box.
>
> It is somewhat like iGoogle widgets where the source for them is feeds, but here the source is web part response output. Does this makes sense or possible to take the web part response and show in a container?

Answer (score 0):

You looking to write a wrapper which can contain a Web Part in itself, but that should again be a Web Part so that it can act like a Widget and can be dropped into Web Part Zones, SharePoint already offers Drag and Drop and treat them as Widgets... The only thing it doesn't offer is collapsible, expandable...

You may look into extending the existing Web Part class to add this functionality... Induce some JavaScript into the existing Web Part to add expandable/collapsible nature! All theory, never tried this :)

**[Short Scope]**
However, if we talk just about ListViews then you can develop a single Visual Web Part which has Custom Visual Web Part Properties to take input the List Url/Name and render it dynamically... In that Web Part you can hide the top bar, and add your custom top bar with expand/collapse feature!

But again this cannot be done for everything... Like there are many OOB Web Parts and you cannot write a wrapper like this for all of them!

Answer (score 0):

Web Part Zones are those containers for Web Parts. They ought to be one of the first things you learned about as a Sharepoint user or developer.

You can add behavior like expand/collapse to any element in a SharePoint page by adding JavaScript.